# Select image and magnify selected image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am experimenting with images gallery as a tab and magnification.

Here is the current code I have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
.img-zoom-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.img-zoom-lens {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.img-zoom-result {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
#myimage:hover{
    opacity: 0;
}
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
}
</style>
<script>
function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  /*insert lens:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
  result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
    if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
    if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
    /*set the position of the lens:*/
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /*display what the lens "sees":*/
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="img-zoom-container">
    <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result">
        <div id="1" class="tabcontent">
            <img id="myimage" src="cdn/images/products/1605983270.webp-300x300.webp" width="300px" height="300px">
        </div>
        <div id="2" class="tabcontent">
            <img id="myimage2" src="cdn/images/products/1606254469.webp-300x300.webp" width="300px" height="300px">
        </div>
        <div id="3" class="tabcontent">
            <img id="myimage3" src="cdn/images/products/1606251762.webp-300x300.webp" width="300px" height="300px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <img onclick="openCity(event, '1')" id="defaultOpen" src="cdn/images/products/1605983270.webp-50x50.webp" width="50px" height="50px">
    <img onclick="openCity(event, '2')" src="cdn/images/products/1606254469.webp-50x50.webp" width="50px" height="50px">
    <img onclick="openCity(event, '3')" src="cdn/images/products/1606251762.webp-50x50.webp" width="50px" height="50px">
<script>
imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");
imageZoom("myimage2", "myresult");
imageZoom("myimage3", "myresult");
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can get either function but not both working at the same time.

I am trying to achieve the effect that I could simply hover over the current selected image to magnify.

My broken example can be found here.

https://smokeology.ca/test.html

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need a magnifying glass example?

Comment: no i got the magnifying glass to work i just cant it to work together with the image selection tab

Comment: https://firebudcannabis.ca/products/pineapple-express-aaa-sativa this is an example of what im trying to do.

Comment: It's like the principle of a magnifying glass.

Comment: not exactly. the scale doesnt work the same way as the site does it from above.

the magnifying glass is only blowing up a specific section.

Comment: look - https://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/magnify-image-hover.html

Comment: i know how to do it the above works partially i was trying to maintain that code for simplicity and less dependancies.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. Is this what you are looking for?

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".imgs");
let abc = document.getElementById("resultimage").src = images[0].src;

function selectIMG(id) {
  var img = document.getElementById("img" + id).src;
  document.getElementById("resultimage").src = img;
}
```

```css
.img-zoom-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.img-zoom-lens {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.img-zoom-result {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#resultimage {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform .25s, visibility .25s ease-in;
}


#resultimage:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-zoom-container">
  <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result">
    <div id="1" class="tabcontent">
      <img id="resultimage" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/536/354.jpg?hmac=i0yVXW1ORpyCZpQ-CknuyV-jbtU7_x9EBQVhvT5aRr0" width="300px" height="300px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<img id="img1" class="imgs" onclick="selectIMG('1')" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/35/536/354.jpg?hmac=jp_Ypjavu2-qfJva-2dR-Mwusv5WWX1CqL5j_o0rPbg" width="50px" height="50px">
<img id="img2" class="imgs" onclick="selectIMG('2')" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/536/354.jpg?hmac=i0yVXW1ORpyCZpQ-CknuyV-jbtU7_x9EBQVhvT5aRr0" width="50px" height="50px">
<img id="img3" class="imgs" onclick="selectIMG('3')" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/302/536/354.jpg?hmac=TC5rkcbi3t6xjOKZygd2O51G1i9ascFddKoeTkPz6bw" width="50px" height="50px">
```

[**Fiddle code**](https://jsfiddle.net/ys6hd4Le/1/)

Comment: selecting the images yes but the hover effect....check this link to know what i mean.

https://firebudcannabis.ca/products/pineapple-express-aaa-sativa